# Powerbuilder Passing a Datastore / object

Tags: powerbuilder

i have a datastore that when retrieve and has results, the rows should be displayed in another window

> ds_1.Retrieve()
>
> > IF ds_1.RowCount() > 0 THEN
> >
> > > ```
> > > i_str_pass.po[1] = ds_1
> > >
> > > OpenWithParm(w_error, i_str_pass)
> > > ```
> >
> > END IF

i_str_pass is a structure and po is a powerobject

i want to display the results of ds_1 in w_error's datawindow without needing to retrieve it again

i tried calling in w_error

> str_pass i_str_pass
>
> i_str_pass = Message.PowerObjectparm
>
> dw_1 = i_str_pass.po[1]

i debugged and saw that I passed it correctly
but the data that was retrieved were not showing at all
anything im doing wrong? thanks in adv.

Comment: is w_error NOT a response window? is ds_1 a local variable?  if so, your reference is going out of scope before the code in w_error can access the now-destroyed datastore object.  There are a couple of ways to handle this depending on you're functionality requirements.

Comment: w_error can be a response window, i did it as a pop up window with a datawindow.

Comment: Wow this was a year ago... I searched google for the same problem on another project, I landed on my question, exactly 1 year ago same date. haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
i_str_pass.po[1]. DYNAMIC ShareData(dw_1)
```

instead of

```
dw_1 = i_str_pass.po[1]
```

Surprised the latter wasn't a runtime error, since you're assigning a DataStore to a DataWindow.

GetFullState/RowsCopy is all fine too, but incurs a memory penalty since you're making a copy of that data (which may or may not be something you're concerned about)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at `GetFullState()`/`SetFullState()` :

```
blobl lbl_data
if i_str_pass.po[1].GetFullState(lbl_data) = 1 then
    dw_1.SetFullState(lbl_data)
end if
```

You could also take a look at `ShareData()` to establish a "link" between 2 DataStores or DataWindows.

Comment: i used RowsCopy after passing it. this way i get to display the rows. im not sure why it doesnt display the rows in the first place but when you call dw_1.Rowcount() .. its there.. 

RowsCopy solved it.

Comment: @Sid: _im not sure why it doesnt display the rows in the first place_ : it is just because you _cannot_ assign directly a datastore to a datawindow. Partly because one is a visual object and not the other. What you did is that you made the dw_1 variable point to a a datastore that the window cannot display. But `RowCount` works on both types so you got the illusion that it works in some way.

Comment: @Sid: MMh, I did not tested but I doubt, because assigning a DW that exist elsewhere to anther window would imply changing its parent. And if you wonder about it, you cannot create a datawindow and retrieve it in memory as you can do with a datatore. If the datawindow is not created on a window, it just "doesn't work" properly. If you need to pass a DS to populate a DW, you need to move some data between the two by `SetFullState()`, `ShareData()`. As you noticed `RowsCopy()` can work but it is more to play with the DW buffers.

Comment: Good catch Seki, I missed the datastore -> datawindow assignment, kind of surprised that wasn't a runtime error.  
@Sid Another option that doesn't make a copy of any data (which may or may not be an issue depending on how much data you're passing around.  Is to use ` i_str_pass.po[1]. DYNAMIC ShareData(dw_1)` as your assignment statement at the end of the w_error script